# How would you design the following table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

My goal is to present the test accuracies achieved by models trained on data sets R1, R2, and R3 in a concise manner. To achieve this, I trained the models in multiple phases, gradually incorporating more data from each of the three sets, rather than starting with the entire data set at once.
[image]

What do you think about it? I'm not quite sure, whether you can avoid having to repeat the data set names for each model. I would appreciate any advice

Comment: What you try? As starting point you can use answer on your previous question ...

Comment: My goal is to present the test accuracies achieved by models trained on data sets R1, R2, and R3 in a concise manner. To achieve this, I trained the models in multiple phases, gradually incorporating more data from each of the three sets, rather than starting with the entire data set at once.

Comment: Wel, we are interested what you try yourself, your goal is obvious. Site is not service "we- do-your- task-instead-of-you>" ...

Comment: @Zarko That was not my intention. Before starting creating the table, I wanted to know whether the design is acceptable. Therefore, I wanted to ask experts (this community). So, whether it is a good design for presenting the results. I am sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: @Zarko But you are right. Next time I will present an example in LaTeX instead of a drawing

Comment: @Mico You're absolutely right. Answering those kinds of questions properly can be time-consuming, so I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My main recommendation is that you transpose the material, mainly so that you have only 4 or 5 columns instead of 10 or more.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Test accuracies achieved by models trained on datasets R1, R2, and~R3}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll ccc @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Model} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Training Phases} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-5} 
&& Phase 1 & Phase 2 & Phase 3 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Decision Tree} \\
& R1 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R2 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R3 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{LSTU} \\
& R1 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R2 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R3 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Average} \\
& R1 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R2 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R3 & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment/request: To insert a new, center-aligned column in the table shown above and to use "Baseline" as the contents of the new header, the main change you need to make is to replace

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll ccc @{}}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll c ccc @{}}
```

Next, change

```
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
```

to

```
\cmidrule(l){4-6}
```

And, of course, don't forget to insert the contents of the new column 3 in the table -- 1 cell for each row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand\ML[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Test accuracies achieved by models trained on datasets R1, R2, and~R3}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll c ccc @{}}
\toprule
\ML{Model} & Baseline & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Training Phases} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-6} 
&&& Phase 1 & Phase 2 & Phase 3 \\
\midrule
\ML{Decision Tree} \\
& R1 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R2 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R3 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\addlinespace
\ML{LSTU} \\
& R1 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R2 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R3 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\addlinespace
\ML{Average} \\
& R1 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R2 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
& R3 & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How would I add another single-line column between Model and Training Phases? I'm trying to understand your LaTeX code, but I haven't quite figured it out yet. I think I need to learn how to create such complex tables. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Unistack - I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "single-line column". If you mean a column with left-aligned contents, just change `\begin{tabular}{@{} ll ccc @{}}` to `\begin{tabular}{@{} lll ccc @{}}` and make the adjustments needed to account for the fact that the contents of what used to be columns 3 thru 5 should now be the contents of columns 4 thru 6.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I don't get the columns aligned. I want to insert a new column named "Baseline" between Model and Training Phases but I mess up the alignments

Comment: @Unistack - Please see the addendum I posted.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is too bad repeating the names. I came up with the following. Depending on your data, you maybe want to use `S` columns from the `siunitx` package and/or put the text in bold (`\textbf{...}`).
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Training phases} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Decision Tree} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{LST M} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Average} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
                                         & R1     & R2     & R3              & R1     & R2     & R3      & R1     & R2     & R3        \\ \midrule
        Training phase 1                 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots          & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots  & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots    \\
        Training phase 2                 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots          & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots  & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots    \\
        Training phase 3                 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots          & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots  & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lorsque je dois faire de tels tableaux, je recours à Excel2latex. C'est une formidable macro d'Excel qui permet de rédiger automatiquement le code LATEX d'un tableau excel. Ça marche super bien, et s'est disponible en ligne en Open Access. Il faut consulter le "Reed me" de ladite macro pour voir les packages nécessaires à son utilisation (bigstruth, colortbl, multirow etc.).

Avec cet outil, vous construisez votre tableau sur Excel. Puis, vous le sélectionné et vous cliquez sur "convert table to latex". En une seconde, cela vous produit le code latex du tableau sélectionné.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) This is an English speaking website so please translate your answer. [Bienvenue sur TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Le site étant anglophone, pouvez-vous traduire votre réponse, s'il-vous-plaît?

Comment: When I need to make such tables, I use Excel2latex. It's a great Excel macro that automatically reproduces the LATEX code of an excel table. It works great, and is available online in Open Access. You have to check the "Reed me" of the macro to see the packages needed to use it (bigstruth, colortbl, multirow etc.).

With this tool, you build your table in Excel. Then you select it and click on "convert table to latex". In one second, it produces the latex code of the selected table.

Comment: I meant that you should edit your answer for it to be in English instead of French.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to make such tables, I use Excel2latex. It's a great Excel macro that automatically reproduces the LaTeX code of an Excel table. It works great, and is available online in Open Access. You have to check the "Read me" of the macro to see the packages needed to use it (bigstruth, colortbl, multirow etc.).

With this tool, you build your table in Excel. Then you select it and click on "convert table to LaTeX". In one second, it produces the LaTeX code of the selected table.